# run sed command on Lua script

Tags: sed, lua

I need run this sed command on Lua script:

```
sed -i "1i sameText" log.txt
```

i can't send var (log file name) to sed on Lua script.

I do:

```
local datafile = log.txt

local date = os.date("%d-%m-%Y,%H:%M:%S")

os.execute('sed -i "1i date,sameText" datafile')
```

**error**:
`sed: no input files`

Comment: probably changing(inside sed) `date` to  `$date` may help. Also the name of this variable is confusing, consider using some other name.

Comment: `os.execute('sed -i "1i '..date..',sameText" '..datafile)`

Answer (score 2):

First, `datafile` should be a string-- not the "txt" field of a probably nonexistent log object.

An easy way to embed variables in Lua strings is to use [string.format](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.format):

```
local datafile = 'log.txt'
local date = os.date("%d-%m-%Y,%H:%M:%S")
local cmd = string.format('sed -i "1i %s,sameText" "%s"', date, datafile)
local r = os.execute(cmd)
```

If you just want to insert text at the beginning of a file, you can also do that in Lua directly without requiring sed:

```
local function prependToFile(filename, txt)
    local hnd = io.open(filename, "rb")
    local s = hnd:read "*a"
    hnd:close()

    local hnd = io.open(filename, "wb")
    hnd:write(txt, "\n", s)
    hnd:close()
end

local datafile = 'log.txt'
local date = os.date("%d-%m-%Y,%H:%M:%S")
prependToFile(datafile, date .. ",sameText")
```